# What methods exist to differentiate form controls being modified programmatically vs being modified by the user?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use angular reactive forms to create a form with text fields.

I pre-populate the fields if the data for the fields have already been stored. Now I can allow the user to navigate to these forms to edit the fields.

I would like to call a function when I edit a text field, which would likely clear other fields below it.

But I do not want the function to clear other fields to get invoked when the text field is being modified programatically, in this case, being pre-populated.

How can I achieve this with angular reactive forms and its APIs? The flags on form controls like `pristine` or `touched` are affected by both user's actions and programmatic pre-population alike.

Comment: Why are you doing that at all? I would be very annoyed if I filled in the form myself, leaving a field out because maybe I had to go and look something up, then went back to add one last value and deleted half of the inputs. Have you user tested this functionality at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've a form in which there are multiple text fields and each has a drop-down implemented with `mat-autocomplete` and `mat-option'. I can only pick values from the drop-down and the values of each drop-down is decided by the option selected in the field above it. Naturally, if I modified the first field, values on every other field below it should clear, as those values in the below fields will not make sense for a different value on the first field.

Comment: `{emitEvent:false}`? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue

Answer (score 2):

If you are modifying the text field programatically set an extra boolean value(eg:modifiedProgramatically = true) and check the boolean value along with the flags on form controls like pristine or touched.

Comment: I would like to have a solution to achieve this with the help of the Angular APis if possible. I can implement it with workarounds by using a flag myself, but want an out-of-the-box solution if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the Angular form approach, but quite simple nevertheless: listen for the input event on the `<input>`, clear the form fields in the callback.

```ts
@Component({
  template: `<input (input)='onUserInput($event)'>`
})
class Example {
  form = new Form({
    something: new FormControl('value')
  })
  onUserInput() {
    this.form.controls.something.setValue(null)
  }
}
```